# Чи існує словник штибу Urban Dictionary для української мови, де б прості користувачі могли додавати тлумачення слів?

Tags: resource-request, українські-словники, словники

Чи існує словник штибу Urban Dictionary для української мови, де б прості користувачі могли додавати тлумачення слів (а також голосувати за найкращі визначення слова? Запитую, бо як я (на жаль) постійно дізнаюся - традиційні українські тлумачні словники (СУМ тощо) не мають величезної кількості українських сленгових слів та діалектизмів (наголошую саме на питомо українські слова, а не різні русизми, полонізми чи англіцизми, які часто помилково включають до сленгу розмовної української мови (вони такими не є).

Наведу приклад. Я походжу з Полтавщини, і хоча там існує дуже велика проблема дикого суржику в усіх містах і селах, але навіть у тому суржику ще не загубилися  велика кількість питомо українських розмовних слів. Наприклад, слово "*невтрисрака*" — це сленг/діалектизм, що означає "погана хазяйка (або ж хазяїн), яка погано доглядає за своїм господарством (напр. посуд не митий, сміття стоїть лусом, всюди пилюка тощо). Якщо це слово загуглити, то воно на всю мережу з'являється двічі (і у обох випадках не на профільних сайтах для словників).

Таких прикладів вдосталь (тобто існує багато питомо українських сленгових слів; у моєму випадку з Полтавського регіону, але я впевнений, що й інші україномовні регіони мають такі питомо українські сленгові слова, про які мені невідомо), й часто-густо Гугл про їхнє існування не знає нічого (були випадки, коли видав 0 результатів пошуку).

UPD: Ось що я знайшов на філологічному сайті ["НоваМова"](http://web.archive.org/web/20100430150011/http://novamova.org/2009/10/urbandicts/) (зараз мертвий). Написано Антоном Шпігуновим у 2009 році:

> Словники бувають різні:дво- і одномовні, орфографічні, етимологічні,
>   тлумачні, спеціальні та ще багато які, однак сьогодні розкажемо Вам
>   про незвичайний вид інтернет-словників.
>
> Це – UrbanDictionary та його російський проект-побратим (читай: клон)
>   СловоНово, словники сучасної лексики, жаргонізмів і сленгу.
>
> Хіба в кожного з нас не бувало моментів, коли ми бачили слова на
>   кшталт “Дичка” (Автомобіль ВАЗ-2110) чи “hinky” (Something as yet
>   undefinable is wrong, out of place; not quite right), але навіть
>   приблизно не знали, що ж воно значить? Звичайно ж, словники сленгу
>   жаргонізмів видаються регулярно, однак таке живе і динамічне явище як
>   розмовна мова неможливо адекватно охопити навіть щорічними
>   перевиданнями таких словників.
>
> Тому ось вони, “живі” словники, що поновлюються самими користувачами
>   щодня, такі ж живі, як і сам пласт мови, який вони прагнуть охопити.
>
> Словники ці можуть стати в нагоді перекладачеві при перекладі
>   новітньої літератури, адже хоча деякі автори, наприклад І. Уелш та Е.
>   Берждесс, іноді й подають словнички в кінці своїх творів, більшість
>   так своїх читачів не балують. Лексикографи тут знайдуть цікаве та
>   новітнє вирішення проблеми охоплення “живої” мови та постійної
>   актуальзації картотеки. А пересічний відвідувач завжди може завітати,
>   щоб відчути справжній народний дух у своїй мові та підняти собі
>   настрій.
>
> До речі, українського аналога цих проектів наразі не існує.

Comment: Ось є приблизно такий, як ви пишете, [Словник закарпатського діалекту](http://words.eugene-home.kiev.ua/).

Comment: Розшукуються насамперед словники сленгу (діалетикзм я вживаю у значенні регіональний сленг) де прості користувачі можуть додавати слова.

Comment: Знайшов ось таку [вікі](http://novamova.wikia.com), яка заявлєя _"Цей проект є спробою систематизувати та категоризувати той сленг, жаргон, нові концепції та неологізми, що ними послуговується сучасна Україна. Залежно від важливості та змісту пояснюваних ідей, їм може відповідатити все від словникової нотатки до енциклопедичної статті чи циклу статей."_, але там всього 16 слів...

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/slangshotUA/ тут щось готують

Comment: Ну дасть Бог вони щось толкове запустять

Comment: 8 тарвня 2020 року з'явивилася недавно ще й "Словникарня" на slovnyk.ua: https://slovnyk.ua/user_dict.php (джерело: https://www.facebook.com/slovnyk.ua/posts/680128076070630)

Answer (score 15):

На r2u є [сучасний народний словник](http://r2u.org.ua/html/announcement.html). Правда, він російсько-український, а не тлумачний, але якщо слово є в російській, то ви можете додати його і переклад з тлумаченням і прикладами вживання. Додавання відбувається через обговорення на [цьому форумі](http://r2u.org.ua/forum/viewforum.php?f=7) в розділі "Обговорення статей".

А [ось форум](http://r2u.org.ua/forum/viewforum.php?f=12) на якому ви зможете додати переклад, тлумачення і приклади вживання до *Загального народного англійсько-українського словника*.

> **Мета**
>
> Створення народного загального високоякісного англійсько-українського
>   словника. В першу чергу цей словник має надавати українські переклади,
>   яких немає в інших словниках (зокрема надсучасні терміни), або
>   переклади яких в наявних словниках є неточними або неповними.
>
> Кожен охочий може запропонувати новий переклад на форумі (зі сторінки
>   пошуку є гіперланка на обговорення запитаного слова), або обговорити
>   наявний.

Ось приклад перекладу, який з'явився лише цього року:
[image]

Також є [форум тлумачного словника](http://r2u.org.ua/forum/viewforum.php?f=46).

---

На Urban Dictionary можна додавати й україномовні слова - ось приклад [курва](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0&defid=9286052)

Comment: Просто вточню для читачів: мається на увазі (1) [«Російсько-український народний сучасний словник» на R2U](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=тест&scope=all&dicts=10&highlight=on), (2) [«Загальний народний англійсько-український словник» на E2U](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=тест&dicts=1&highlight=on) та (3) [«Тлумачно-стилістичний словник української мови» на R2U](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=автівка&scope=all&dicts=15&highlight=on).

Comment: Розшукується тлумачний словник (тобто українсько-український)

Answer (score 8):

Хоча там не можна додавати власні слова, бо це вже опубліковані книги, не можна не згадати про праці [Лесі Ставицької](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%96%D1%97%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0):

- [Український жарґон. Словник](https://toloka.to/t10945) - лише цензурний сленг
- [Українська мова без табу. Словник нецензурної лексики та її відповідників. Обсценізми, евфемізми, сексуалізми](https://toloka.to/t28701) - нецензурна лайка

Comment: Це непогані словники, але бажано платформа де прості користувачі можуть додавати визначення. Щось штибу сайту "Словотвору" (http://slovotvir.org.ua/), але де акцент був би на українському питомому слензі.

Comment: Коли я іду на цей сайт, я бачи тільки "Такої теми чи такого повідомлення не існує" - чи ви знаєте чому так?  Можливо це тому що я в USA?

Comment: @weronika це тому що повидаляли чомусь

Answer (score 7):

А як же словник "Мислово" ([myslovo.com](http://myslovo.com))? Це ж і є той самий сленговий словник. У ньому, правда, нема дуже розгорнутих статей, але все одно заслуговує уваги. Наприклад, якщо вам потрібно дізнатися, що таке "швидка Настя" чи "педик", то там усе це є.

Comment: Не бачу, де б там користувач міг додавати свої інтерпретації до вже наявних слів (чи підтримується там можливість декількох інтерпретацій в одного слова?). Чи голосувати за інтерпретації. І дописи там з'являються лише після перевірки редактором. Але так — загалом схоже.

Comment: Це найкращий поки варіант, але як слушно зазначив Sasha не бачу можливості додати додаткові користувацькі тлумачення до вже існуючих слів - що є a killing feature онлайн словника такого типу. Також інтерфейс/функціонал сайту залишають бажати кращого - то й же Словотвір на голову вище.

Answer (score 6):

У сайту СУМ-11 є розділ, де можна додавати свої слова:
http://sum.in.ua/f/

Також, як вже було згадано в одному з коментарів, на UrbanDictionary можна додавати українські слова. І, судячи з того, що люди хоч мало, але таки голосують за тлумачення, то сайт відвідуваний в тому числі й українцями.

Колись навіть додав [слово](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B8) із діалектним значенням зі свого регіону.

Comment: На UrbanDictionary проблема лиш у тому, що абетково вся кирилка перемішана безвідносно до мови. Там і болгарська, і російська, і, мабуть, ще купа кирилкових мов. Але загалом так, думаю, немає перешкод писати туди щось українською, хай буде ще й вона)

Answer (score 3):

Також з новіших є:

- [SlangZone](https://www.slangzone.net)
- [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/)

Інтерфейс приємніший, користування простіше.