# Does Ukrainian language have an equivalent of Urban Dictionary?

Tags: терміни, неологізми, сленг

Does Ukrainian language have an online dictionary that records slang, tech terms, new words, simplified words, etc.? Something like Urban Dictionary perhaps?

Чи має українська мова онлайн словник, який записує сленг, технічні терміни, нові слова, спрощені слова та інші? Можливо, щось на зразок Urban Dictionary?

EDIT:

I just found http://slovotvir.org.ua from this [question](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/229), but it relies on Facebook for adding words and hence slow and labor intensive.

Я знайшов http://slovotvir.org.ua з цього [question](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/229), але він спирається на Facebook для додавання слів, що є повільно та трудомістко.

The same question has a link to [NASU Institute of Ukrainian Language](http://www1.nas.gov.ua/institutes/ium/about/Pages/default.aspx), which appears to be a soviet-style state owned bureaucracy. It would take it a century to map existing words, not to mention bridge the gap between new words as they appear in English and other languages and Ukrainian in real time.

Те саме питання має посилання на [Інститут української мови НАН України] (http://www1.nas.gov.ua/institutes/ium/about/Pages/default.aspx), який, здається, є державною у радянському стилі бюрократією. Це займе століття для запису існуючих слів, не кажучи вже про те, щоб подолати розрив між новими словами, як вони з'являються в англійській та інших мовах та українською мовою в реальному часі.

Is there something that has the same efficiency as Urban Dictionary where anyone can add a word in less than a minute like screens below and either Google do the sorting and ranking like Urban Dictionary or have own ranking system?

Чи є щось, що має таку ж ефективність, як Urban Dictionary, де кожен може додати слово менш ніж за хвилину, як на екранах нижче, та Google робить сортування та рейтинг, також як Urban Dictionary, або має власну систему рейтингу?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1096/331 Especially since question is posed in both English and Ukrainoan

Comment: @Sasha Ви бачили моє повідомлення згори? Чому це питання досі не позначено як Duplicate?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it does / Так, має:

http://myslovo.com/

Any user can add their own words there / Його наповнюють користувачі, й ви можете самостійно додавати туди слова.

[image]

Here's the page to add your own words / Ось сторінка [додавання слів](http://myslovo.com/?page_id=2):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there exists [SlangZone](https://www.slangzone.net/), which is far more advanced in terms of functionality, user experience and overall looks.